# R equivalent of Python's np.dot for 3D array

Tags: python, arrays, r, numpy, matrix

I am translating some code from Python to R involving 3D matrices. Which is tricky as I know very little Python or matrix algebra. Anyhow in the Python code I have a matrix dot.product as follows: `np.dot(A, B)`. Matrix A has dimension (10, 4) and B is (2, 4, 2).  (These dimensions may vary but always will match on the second dimension). So np.dot has no problem with this as from the documentation:

> "For 2-D arrays it is equivalent to matrix multiplication, and for 1-D
>   arrays to inner product of vectors (without complex conjugation). For
>   N dimensions it is a sum product over the last axis of a and the
>   second-to-last of b:"

Therefore it multiplies along the second axis of A=4, and the middle axis of B=4 and outputs a (10,2,2) matrix. => No problem. However in R, `%*%` does not have this behaviour and throws a 'non-conformable array' error.

Toy example in r:

```
A <- matrix( rnorm(10*4), nrow=10, ncol=4)
B <- array( rnorm(2*4*2), c(2,4,2))
A %*% B
Error in A %*% B : non-conformable arrays
```

How can I resolve this to achieve the same calculation as `np.dot`?

Comment: `B` is a 2-D array, for a 3-D array you need function `array()`. Also you used `%%` and not `%*%`.

Comment: Thanks yes I should use `array()` and `%*%`. There were typos! Fixing now. Anyhow - result is the same after they are fixed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can do this with `aperm()` and `tensor::tensor`. Using @SandipanDey's example.

Set up arrays (you need `aperm` to get the appropriate B, which I call B2 here):

```
A <- matrix(0:39,ncol=4,byrow=TRUE)
B <- array(0:15,dim=c(2,4,2))
B2 <- aperm(B,c(2,1,3),resize=TRUE)
```

`tensor::tensor` does the right computation, but we need to reshape the result:

```
library(tensor)
C <- tensor(A,B2,2,1)
aperm(C,c(3,2,1),resize=TRUE)
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you thats exactly what I was looking for. Didn't know about the `tensor` package I shall have to familiarise myself!

Answer (score 3):

Let's first try to understand the order of filling multidimensional arrays in `python numpy` and in `R`, they are different.

In `python`

```
import numpy as np
np.arange(16).reshape((2,4,2)) # fill with 0:15

#[[[ 0  1]
#  [ 2  3]
#  [ 4  5]
#  [ 6  7]]

# [[ 8  9]
#  [10 11]
#  [12 13]
#  [14 15]]]
```

In `R`

```
array(0:15, dim=c(2,4,2)) # fill with 0:15
#, , 1
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    0    2    4    6
#[2,]    1    3    5    7
#, , 2
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    8   10   12   14
#[2,]    9   11   13   15
```

Now having an understanding of the fill order, let's try to emulate `np.dot` in R with the same data, `A,B` as the input arrays and `C` as the output array (for that we shall need to change order of dimensions):

In `python`:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(40).reshape((10,4))    # 0:39
b = np.arange(16).reshape((2,4,2))   # 0:15

print a
[[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]
 [12 13 14 15]
 [16 17 18 19]
 [20 21 22 23]
 [24 25 26 27]
 [28 29 30 31]
 [32 33 34 35]
 [36 37 38 39]]

print b
[[[ 0  1]
  [ 2  3]
  [ 4  5]
  [ 6  7]]

 [[ 8  9]
  [10 11]
  [12 13]
  [14 15]]]

print np.dot(a, b)
[[[  28   34]
  [  76   82]]

 [[  76   98]
  [ 252  274]]

 [[ 124  162]
  [ 428  466]]

 [[ 172  226]
  [ 604  658]]

 [[ 220  290]
  [ 780  850]]

 [[ 268  354]
  [ 956 1042]]

 [[ 316  418]
  [1132 1234]]

 [[ 364  482]
  [1308 1426]]

 [[ 412  546]
  [1484 1618]]

 [[ 460  610]
  [1660 1810]]]
```

In `R` to get the same result we need the following code:

```
A <- matrix(0:39, nrow=10, byrow=TRUE) # 0:39
A
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    0    1    2    3
 [2,]    4    5    6    7
 [3,]    8    9   10   11
 [4,]   12   13   14   15
 [5,]   16   17   18   19
 [6,]   20   21   22   23
 [7,]   24   25   26   27
 [8,]   28   29   30   31
 [9,]   32   33   34   35
[10,]   36   37   38   39

B <- array(0, dim=c(4,2,2)) # notice the change in dimensions
B[,,1] <- matrix(0:7, nrow=4, byrow=TRUE)
B[,,2] <- matrix(8:15, nrow=4, byrow=TRUE)
B                                 # 0:15
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    1
[2,]    2    3
[3,]    4    5
[4,]    6    7

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    8    9
[2,]   10   11
[3,]   12   13
[4,]   14   15

C <- array(0, dim=c(2,2,10)) # again note the change in dimensions
for (i in 1:10) {
  for (j in 1:2) {
    for (k in 1:2) {
      C[k,j,i] = sum(A[i,]*B[,j,k])
    }
  }
}
C
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   28   34
[2,]   76   82

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   76   98
[2,]  252  274

, , 3

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  124  162
[2,]  428  466

, , 4

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  172  226
[2,]  604  658

, , 5

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  220  290
[2,]  780  850

, , 6

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  268  354
[2,]  956 1042

, , 7

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  316  418
[2,] 1132 1234

, , 8

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  364  482
[2,] 1308 1426

, , 9

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  412  546
[2,] 1484 1618

, , 10

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  460  610
[2,] 1660 1810
```

We can see the results are exactly same. Now you can try with your own data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but something doens't make sense to me - i.e. `# notice the change in dimensions`. You have defined a (4, 2, 2) matrix but mine is a (2, 4, 2) matrix coming as a result from another function.

Comment: If you dont have access to the function then you can write a small transform function that changes the array  output to the desired format if required. All I am trying to communicate is that the order of the dimensions needs  to be different from numpy if you are creating an array on your own. If the function that returns the array returns it in correct format then we should be fine.